# How do I get WordPress emails working on OpenShift?

Tags: openshift

I installed WordPress using OpenShift's default package. Emails are not being sent (default welcome message and forgotten password link, new user, etc). What do I have to do to get these working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are probably getting blocked by the spam filter.  I would recommend that you using something like sendgrid, gmail, or mailgun and configure WordPress to use them as a third party service to get your emails to be consistent.

Comment: Good thought! Turns out my gear's IP—184.73.12.206—is on Spamhaus ZEN. I used WP SMTP to send through my Turbo SMTP account. That worked.